# Apollo and AwsAppsync repeating mutation in callback

Tags: graphql, apollo, aws-appsync

I have an awsAppSync client that is set up as follows:

```
that._getClient = function() {
        return  client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
            url: appSyncUrl,
            region: AWS.config.region,
            auth: {
                type: AUTH_TYPE.AWS_IAM,
                credentials: AWS.config.credentials
            }
        });
    }
```

And a mutate function that is called like this:

```
that.mutate = function(mutation, variables) {
  let client = that._getClient();
  return client.mutate({ mutation: mutation, fetchPolicy: 'no-cache', variables: variables })
  .then(function (result){
    return result;
  });
}
```

I need to make subsequent queries to create different records that depend on one another, so I'm returning the Id of the newly created record to use in the callback of the previous query.

The problem is, that in every callback where the mutate function is called, the mutation that caused this callback gets executed again. For example, I do:

```
appSync.mutate(mutation, requestParams)
.then(function (response) {
let id = response.id
requestParams = {//new stuff}
return appSync.mutate(mutation, requestParams)
        })
.then(//and so forth)
```

Now, I've seen some posts on here that say that it might be something to do with the optimistic response, and so on, but I actually get two new records in my database. I also considered the cache doing something trippy, but As you can see from the code, I (think) disabled it for the mutation.

Please help.